# DLL clr function not linking properly

Tags: c++, dll, clr

Hi I am having a problem with linking to a dll when I call the constructor for a dll's class to create an object.  There seems to be some conflict between a call from a function that has a call convention of clrcall to the dll's cdecl constructor.  Both dll and application have /clr and they seem to compile fine but not link.  Here is the linking error...

> ContactSet.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0002FC) "public:
>   __cdecl DatalinkSimCORBA_Interface::DatalinkSimCORBA_Interface(void)" (??0DatalinkSimCORBA_Interface@@$$FQEAA@XZ) referenced in function
>   "public: __clrcall DatalinkSim::CContactSet::CContactSet(void)"
>   (??0CContactSet@DatalinkSim@@$$FQE$AAM@XZ)

I added the dll reference using the project properties framework and reference page using visual studio also.  Any ideas on why this is choking on link step?

Comment: I thought references were for `.net` / clr not native dlls.

Comment: The dll is clr and I have selected /clr for Common Language Runtime Support in the visual studio property pages.

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong, forgetting to link the import library for the native DLL is a standard mistake.

Comment: Do I have to import the dll manually in the code?

Comment: No.  Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting.  Add the .lib file of the DLL.

Comment: I was pretty sure that you either create a dll or a lib file.  Dynamic link library or a static library.  Not both.  Can you explain this adding the lib version of the dll?

Comment: I did try to just build a static library and then i linked the way you told me and removed the dll reference using the visual studio add reference page...I don't know why this is not working for DLL